# Twitter updates of the people I follow

Tags: twitter, tweet

Does Twitter operate on the principle that people with whom we interact (the most) only their updates are shown in our timeline?

One of my fiends is tweeting but am not getting his/her tweets. Whereas other friends' tweets are showing in my timeline.

Or has it to do with the handle me and my friends follow (in common) and my friend replies to them will show in my timeline? And the ones which we don't follow in common will not show in my timeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweets from your friend whom you are following, starting with an @mention are only shown in your Timeline if you also follow the @mentioned friend. If you want everyone to see the tweet it shouldn't start with an @mention. That is why sometimes people start just with a "." > ".@mention tweet".

Comment: `Whereas other friends' tweets are showing in my TL.` are shown in my TL even when I am not following @mention person my friends are mentioning (but the tweets dont start with @mention)!